# Aligning columns for different panels in the same table

Tags: tables, spacing

As shown in the code below, I have a table with two panels, each panel has different number of columns. I want the columns of Panel B to be evenly spaced relative to Panel A. As it currently stands, I am not able to align the columns of Panel B with Panel A. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[font=bf, labelsep=none, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]   
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{center}
  \caption{\\ \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont  \normalfont Here's a title for the table.
}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{13}{D{.}{.}{4}}@{}}

\multicolumn{4}{l}{Panel A. Here's a title} & & & & & & & & & & \\


\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Subtitle here} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Subtitle here} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-7} \cmidrule(l){8-14} 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$<$10\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10-30\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{30-50\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{50-70\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$>$70\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$<$10\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10-20\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20-30\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{30-40\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{40-50\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$>$50\%} \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{1}{l}{group 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.228} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.056} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{16} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{group 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.343} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.126} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{12} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{group 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.495} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{15} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.212} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{group 4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.639} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.258} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{group 5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.747} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.260} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} \\

\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Panel B. Here's a slightly longer title} & & & & & & & & \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\widehat{\alpha}$ ($p$-value)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\widehat{\sigma}_{\varepsilon}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{IR} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\widehat{\beta}^{m}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\widehat{\beta}^{s}$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\widehat{\beta}^{h}$}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\widehat{\beta}^{u}$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Std. Dev.}  \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{2}{l}{group 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.216 (0.366)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2.297} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.094} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.865} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.234}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.164}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.216}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.403} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4.856}  \\




\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont here's something description for the table
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Panel A has 14 columns, Panel B has 10. Please clarify what you mean by "I want the columns of Panel B to be evenly spaced relative to Panel A." Also, the tabular material appears to be quite a bit wider than the text block -- is this by design?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure how to explain it but if you can imagine each column having width 1.4, so that in total the length is 10*1.4=14. Regarding the tabular material and text block, is there a possible way to force the table material to be same width as the text? If so, I'd appreciate you showing me too. Thanks.

Comment: I also do not understand what you mean. you could use `p{1cm}` columns and force all the column widths, but currently the second part of the table is in the same `tabular` as the first, so they are aligned. You could use an image editor and just edit the above image to show what output you want.  the text will be narrower if you use \small or \footnotesize  to make it fit the space or better just design the headings not to be so much wider than the data, which wastes a lot of space

Comment: @TrueTears - Please see the approach I took in my answer: I set up two separate `tabular*` environments, each with a pre-set width of `\textwidth`. Does this address one of your questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the structures of the two panels seem to have virtually nothing in common except for the labels in the very first column, I can't think of a good reason for attempting to line up the columns of the two tabulars. Indeed, I would use two separate `tabular*` environment, with each column structure optimized separately. I would also get rid of virtually all `\multicolumn` "wrappers" -- their use can only be justified in the header rows. (Aside: Who on earth taught you to encase every single cell in a `\multicolumn` wrapper -- that person has a lot of explaining to do...) Do simplify the material in the header row; this will allow to get by with choosing `\small` as the font size. (Conversely, if you keep all those `%` symbols in the header cells, you'll have to switch to `\footnotesize` or even `\scriptsize` in order to make the table fit.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]   
\small
\captionsetup{font={small,bf}}
% We use 'tabular*' to auto-determine intercolumn whitespace:
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 

\caption{Here's a title for the table}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}d{1.3} d{1.0} *{4}{d{2.0}} d{1.3} d{2.0} *{5}{d{1.0}} }
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Panel A. Here's a title} \\
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Ranges (in percent)} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Ranges (in percent)} \\
\cmidrule{2-7} \cmidrule{8-14} 
& \mc{Mean} & \mc{$<$10} & \mc{10--30} & \mc{30--50} & \mc{50--70} & \mc{$>$70} 
& \mc{Mean} & \mc{$<$10} & \mc{10--20} & \mc{20--30} & \mc{30--40} & \mc{40--50} & \mc{$>$50} \\
\midrule
group 1 & 0.228 & 4 & 11 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0.056 & 16 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
group 2 & 0.343 & 0 & 9 & 9 & 1 & 1 & 0.126 & 12 & 3 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
group 3 & 0.495 & 0 & 0 & 15 & 4 & 1 & 0.212 & 8 & 4 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
group 4 & 0.639 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 6 & 10 & 0.258 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 0 & 4 \\
group 5 & 0.747 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 3 & 14 & 0.260 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{8}{d{2.3}} *{2}{d{1.3}}}
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Panel B. Here's a slightly longer title} \\
\toprule
 & \mc{$\hat{\alpha}$} & \mc{($p$-value)} & \mc{$\hat{\sigma}_{\varepsilon}$} & \mc{IR} & \mc{$\hat{\beta}^{m}$} & \mc{$\hat{\beta}^{s}$} & \mc{$\hat{\beta}^{h}$} & \mc{$\hat{\beta}^{u}$} & \mc{Mean} & \mc{Std.\ Dev.}  \\
\midrule
group 1 & 0.216 & (0.366) & 2.297 & 0.094 & 0.865 & -0.234  & -0.164  & -0.216 & 0.403 &  4.856 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
Here's a description for the table
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico, this is great, out of curiosity, what if I wanted to keep the original table where the tabular width was greater than the text, how could I make the second panel span the same width as panel A but still maintain its "even" spacing?

Comment: @TrueTears - If you wanted to make the second `tabular*` environment wider than `\textwidth`, all you would need to do is change the first argument of the `tabular*` environment from `\textwidth` to, say, `1.5\textwidth`.

Comment: @TrueTears - Another option you may want to consider is to transpose the tabular material of both panels. That way, you'd have only 6 columns per tabular (the basic left-hand column plus columns for group1, group2, ..., group5). Typesetting these transposed panels in an appealing way should be rather easy.